# Docker + Xdebug + VSCode Could not connect to client

Tags: php, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, xdebug

PHP version: 7.1.20

XDebug version: 2.7.0

I'm using a Docker container on MacOS Mojave.
On pressing "F5", it shows debug options Pause, Restart, and Stop. But Step Over, Step Into, Step Out are disabled.

I'm kind of learner because I was used to code till 2012-13 on Windows OS. After that year, I am back to coding this month. :) Even after reviewing a lot of posts on Google about how to resolve this issue, I'm not sure how to finally make it work. Please help.

My `launch.json` file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9001,
            "log": true,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceFolder}/learn"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9001
        }
    ]
}
```

XDebug `php.ini` config:

```
xdebug.remote_host = 172.20.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9001
xdebug.scream = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.show_local_vars = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_log = "/var/www/html/xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey = "VSCODE"
```

XDebug logfile (from setting xdebug.remote_log in php.ini):

```
[12] Log opened at 2019-05-12 10:16:44
[12] I: Checking remote connect back address.
[12] I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[12] I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
[12] I: Remote address found, connecting to 172.20.0.1:9001.
[12] W: Creating socket for '172.20.0.1:9001', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[12] E: Could not connect to client. :-(
[12] Log closed at 2019-05-12 10:16:44
```

Debug console:

```
<- launchResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 2,
  command: 'launch',
  success: true }
```

Here's the `dockerfile`.

```
FROM php:7.1.20-apache

RUN apt-get -y update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

# Install tools & libraries
RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils nano wget dialog \
    build-essential git curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev zip

# Install important libraries
RUN apt-get -y install --fix-missing apt-utils build-essential git curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev zip \
    libmcrypt-dev libsqlite3-dev libsqlite3-0 mysql-client zlib1g-dev \
    libicu-dev libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev

# Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# PHP Extensions
RUN pecl install xdebug-2.7.0 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_sqlite \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install curl \
    && docker-php-ext-install tokenizer \
    && docker-php-ext-install json \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install mbstring \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && pecl install redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis

# Enable apache modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Here's the `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: "3"

services:
  webserver:
    build: 
      context: ./bin/webserver
    container_name: '7.1.x-webserver'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links: 
      - mysql
    volumes: 
      - ${DOCUMENT_ROOT-./www}:/var/www/html
      - ${PHP_INI-./config/php/php.ini}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${VHOSTS_DIR-./config/vhosts}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${LOG_DIR-./logs/apache2}:/var/log/apache2
  mysql:
    build: ./bin/mysql
    container_name: '5.7-mysql'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes: 
      - ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR-./data/mysql}:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR-./logs/mysql}:/var/log/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: tiger
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: 'sc-phpmyadmin'
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes: 
      - /sessions
  redis:
    container_name: 'sc-redis'
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you provide your dockerfile and docker-compose?

Comment: @EfratLevitan I edited the question with dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file code. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you need to expose port `9001` for xdebug. I've added an example let me know how you get on.

Comment: Quick eyes @Sarcoma

Comment: @SweetChillyPhilly They weren't when I had to do it myself a few weeks back...

Comment: @gautamlakum Have you managed to resolve your issue?

Comment: Just download this image https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/edersonbadeca/php72-xdebug

Answer (score 5):

You can have your docker container **connect to your host** by configuring PHP appropriately.

Note that I've used Docker's `host.docker.internal` domain, that always points to the host IP.

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=docker
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
```

There's *no need to open ports* to the docker container. 
Just make sure that your debugging application can listen on the appointed port (9000 in my case) and that this port is not occupied.

Take for example this PhpStorm configuration: 
[image: Configuration]

**Troubleshooting**

Validate that xdebug is installed, run in the php container:

`php -i | grep xdebug`

Make sure that you're editing the appropriate `.ini` files, check:

`php -i | grep \.ini`

If you have idekey enabled, make sure to configure them in your IDE too:

[image: config remote debug]

There's a Debugger Config Validator in PhpStorm if you're exposing PHP scripts on a webserver:

[image: Validate]

Comment: For some reason `remote_connect_back=1` does not work (event with the correctly resolved ip address). That is why I prefer to use recommended remote_host configuration `host.docker.internal` - And VIOLA! Thank you

Comment: remote_connect_back option shouldn't be used in a docker configuration... It will make xdebug ignore the remote_host ip setting!

Answer (score 3):

Try to open port `9001` in the `docker-compose.yml` by inserting:

```
ports:
 - "9001:9001"
```

*Example*

```
services:
  webserver:
    build: 
      context: ./bin/webserver
    container_name: '7.1.x-webserver'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "9001:9001"
    links: 
      - mysql
    volumes: 
      - ${DOCUMENT_ROOT-./www}:/var/www/html
      - ${PHP_INI-./config/php/php.ini}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${VHOSTS_DIR-./config/vhosts}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${LOG_DIR-./logs/apache2}:/var/log/apache2
```

See more about configuring docker-compose.yml: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

You might be able to use `expose`. We have that in some of our old Dockerfiles which is intended to allow xDebug connections, but I haven't used it personally.

```
    expose:
      - "9001"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should open port 9001 in your host machine, not in Docker.
2. Also try to check if Xdebug is configured properly: add phpinfo() to your code and open that page in browser. You shold see xdebug enabled
3. If Xdebug enabled, maybe your IDE settings are incorrect

Answer (score 1):

For VSCode as the OP has asked and xdebug 3.x.x, the configuration should be -

```json
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.start_upon_error=yes
xdebug.client_host=[IP address] <<<< NOTE
xdebug.discover_client_host=true
xdebug.client_port=9000
```

**Note:** `xdebug.client_host` should have the host IP address for vscode (192.168...) and not `host.docker.internal` which does not seem to work for vscode.

**Note 2:** There is no need to open any port (9000 in the config above) for this purpose. This could be because docker connects back to host at port 9000 and not vice versa!